# Modifing redirect URL in CAS

Tags: deployment, load-balancing

Is it possible to modify redirect URL in CAS server based on user? Lets say i have 2 versions of application (a.com and b.com). User tries to login into a.com , gets redirected to CAS server, if login is successful i want to redirect him to b.com (with authentication completed). Application are running on Wildfly servers (if that matters). Basically i want some users to have access to new version of my app which is deployed on another server without them knowing that they use it (i think it's called A/B testing). Is there a way to achieve it with CAS server or maybe there are some other tools?

Answer (score 2):

In case it's not too late, this is possible simply with the authentication and validation filters.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
  <param-value>a.com/cas</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>serverName</param-name>
  <param-value>a.com</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>tolerance</param-name>
  <param-value>30000</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can filter users filter-mapping.